# select element in a list jQuery

Tags: jquery

I trying to select all `li` elements at second level of the list add the special class to them. I have made several attempts without success. So the `li`elements that I target are the level just below Comedies, Tragedies and Histories.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('li').next().addClass('special');
    });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    .special {
        font-style: italic;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h2>Selected Shakespeare Plays</h2>
        <ul id="selected-plays" class="clear-after">
            <li>Comedies
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/asyoulikeit/">As You Like It</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>All's Well That Ends Well</li>
                    <li>A Midsummer Night's Dream</li>
                    <li>Twelfth Night</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Tragedies
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="hamlet.pdf">Hamlet</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>Macbeth</li>
                    <li>Romeo and Juliet</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Histories
                <ul>
                    <li>Henry IV (
                        <a href="mailto:henryiv@king.co.uk">email</a>)
                        <ul>
                            <li>Part I</li>
                            <li>Part II</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://www.shakespeare.co.uk/henryv.htm">Henry V</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>Richard II</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#selected-plays > li > ul > li').addClass('special');
        });

</script>
```

Comment: But "Part I" and "Part II" is effected .. those are li at third level. I believe

Comment: Didn't check the full html to notice part 1 Part 2. Updated the post with a fix.

Comment: Nope .. that's not working i put it on the html but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

or

```
$('#selected-plays li').find('li').addClass('special');
```

there are many ways to find children in collections

Comment: I understand that but that means you selected all the children below the il that you are selecting. Would you be able to target the one just below the current il (children but not descendent). Is there anyway for it not pick "Part I" and "Part I" on the list

Comment: you can target it instad use ´$('#selected-plays>li').find('>ul>li').addClass('special');´ if you only want direct children